# aspnetcore 2.0 with EF6 and dotConnect for oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, dotconnect

I am trying to use Oracle using dotConnect for Oracle(v 9.4). Since aspnet core 2.0 has full support to reference older .net framework, I am trying to connect to database using a regular .net assembly(i.e assembly containing my DbContext is in targeting .net 4.6.1 and is been referred in my asp.net core 2 project).

I am facing the below issue

```
"System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.'

Inner Exception: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

Here is my `CodeConfig` class

```
public class CodeConfig : DbConfiguration
{
        public CodeConfig()
        {
            SetProviderServices("Devart.Data.Oracle", Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.OracleEntityProviderServices.Instance);
            SetProviderFactory("Devart.Data.Oracle", new Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleProviderFactory());
        }
}
```

My DbContext class

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(CodeConfig))]
public partial class MyEntities : DataContext, IMyStoredProcedures
{
  public MyEntities(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            Configure();
        }

        private void Configure()
        {
            this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
            this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }    

    }
...
}
```

> **Exception is thrown when `base(nameOrConnectionString)` is executed.**

DI in startup

```
var dbContext = new MyEntities(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]);
services.AddScoped<IDataContextAsync>(provider => dbContext);
services.AddScoped<IMyStoredProcedures>(provider => dbContext);
```

Appsettings.json

```
"Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "metadata=res://Org.MyApp.Entities/MyModel.csdl|res://Org.MyApp.Entities/MyModel.ssdl|res://Org.MyApp.Entities/MyModel.msl;provider=Devart.Data.Oracle;provider connection string=&quot;User Id=UID;Password=****;Server=Server;Persist Security Info=True&quot;"
    }
  }
```

The following links are used as reference.

1. [Getting started Asp.net core with EF6](http://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html)
2. [aspnet core 1.x with EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6)(Based on 1.x but has useful information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many tries, I finally was able to crack through this.

1. quot; in connection string should be replaced with '
2. Instead of targeting netcoreapp2.0, target your aspnetcore 2.0 application to net461 or any full framework higher than that (Look for net461 in your aspnetcore 2.0 csproj file)
3. Add EF >=6.1 from nuget to your modal/entities assembly. Reference `Devart.Data`, `DevArt.Data.Oracle`. `Devart.Data.Oracle.Entoty.EF6` in the same assembly.
4. Create a class OracleDbConfiguration Derived from `DevArt.Data.Entity.OracleEntityProviderServicesConfiguration`

> ```
> public class OracleDbConfiguration : OracleEntityProviderServicesConfiguration// : DbConfiguration
> {
>     public OracleDbConfiguration()
>     {
>          SetProviderServices("Devart.Data.Oracle", OracleEntityProviderServices.Instance);
>          SetProviderFactory("Devart.Data.Oracle", OracleProviderFactory.Instance);
>     }
> }
> ```

5. Decorate your DbContext class with it. E.g.

   `[DbConfigurationType(typeof(OracleDbConfiguration))]`
6. Create a static constructor on your DbContext class and fill it like this

> ```
> static MyEntities()
> {
>     var config = Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.Configuration.OracleEntityProviderConfig.Instance;
>     config.CodeFirstOptions.ColumnTypeCasingConventionCompatibility = false;
> }
> ```

When I get a chance, I will upload a simple app which has the complete solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I didn't have to do anything involving Devart, but some combination of using `'` over `"` in the connection string and targeting `net461` with my .Net Core MVC app seems to have done the trick. Thank you!!!